# How can I add an alias for my pwd to an existing file?

Tags: shell, alias, cd-command

I want to add another alias to my "aliases" file for the directory I'm currently in (Present Working Directory)

I've tried

```
printf "alias aaa=cd " + pwd >> myfile
```

It's close, but I end up getting:

```
alias aaa=durrantm@Castle2012-Ubuntu-laptop01:~/Dropnot/webs/rails_v3/linker
```

instead of:

```
alias aaa=cd ~/Dropnot/webs/rails_v3/linker/
```

In other words, my machine-user name are there and I don't want them, I want the pwd at time of execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
echo "alias aaa='cd \"$PWD\"'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```